# Linear Independence of Union of Two Bases Implies Trivial Intersection?

Tags: linear-algebra

In Carl D. Meyer's "Matrix Analysis and Applied Linear Algebra," section 5.9, question 5 asks

> For a general vector space, let $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ be two subspaces with respective bases $\mathcal{B}_{\mathcal{X}}=\left\{x_{1},\dots,x_{m}\right\}$ and $\mathcal{B}_{\mathcal{Y}}=\left\{y_{1},\dots,y_{n}\right\}$.
>
> 1. Prove that $\mathcal{X}\cap\mathcal{Y}=\left\{0\right\}$ if and only if $\left\{x_{1},\dots,x_{m},y_{1},\dots,y_{n}\right\}$ is a linearly independent set.
> 2. Does $\mathcal{B}_{\mathcal{X}}\cup\mathcal{B}_{\mathcal{Y}}$ being linearly independent imply $\mathcal{X}\cap\mathcal{Y}=\left\{0\right\}$?

For the "if" direction in question one, I suppose that $\left\{x_{1},\dots,x_{m},y_{1},\dots,y_{n}\right\}$ is linearly independent and let $v\in\mathcal{X}\cap\mathcal{Y}$, which means there exist coefficients, with respect to both bases, such that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{m}\alpha_{i}x_{i}=v=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}y_{i}.$$
Then, we get that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{m}\alpha_{i}x_{i}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}y_{i}=0.$$
Since $\left\{x_{1},\dots,x_{m},y_{1},\dots,y_{n}\right\}$ is linearly independent, then each $\alpha_{i}=0$ and each $\lambda_{i}=0$. Thus, $v=0$, so $\mathcal{X}\cap\mathcal{Y}=\left\{0\right\}$.

In the textbook's proof of the "if" direction, their work is the same as mine, but they replace "$\left\{x_{1},\dots,x_{m},y_{1},\dots,y_{n}\right\}$" with "$\mathcal{B}_{\mathcal{X}}\cup\mathcal{B}_{\mathcal{Y}}$", but doesn't this contradict the second question? The book's answer for the second question is to take $\mathcal{X}$ as the $xy$-plane and $\mathcal{Y}$ as the $yz$-plane in $\mathbb{R^{3}}$, with $\mathcal{B}_{\mathcal{X}}=\left\{e_{1},e_{2}\right\}$ and $\mathcal{B}_{\mathcal{Y}}=\left\{e_{2},e_{3}\right\}$. $\mathcal{B}_{\mathcal{X}}\cup\mathcal{B}_{\mathcal{Y}}=\left\{e_{1},e_{2},e_{3}\right\}$ is linearly independent, but $\mathcal{X}\cap\mathcal{Y}\ne\left\{0\right\}$.

So, my question is how does question two not contradict the "if" direction of question one? I am not seeing how they are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you're asking, the difference is that it might happen, as the example in the book gives, that $\mathcal{B}_{\mathcal{X}} \cup \mathcal{B}_{\mathcal{Y}} \neq \left\{ x_1, \dots, x_m, y_1, \dots, y_n \right\}$ where by different I mean that in the right-hand side you might be writing twice the same vector. Exactly as in the example provided:
$$
\mathcal{B}_{\mathcal{X}} \cup \mathcal{B}_{\mathcal{Y}} = \left\{ e_1, e_2, e_3 \right\} \neq \left\{e_1, e_2, e_2, e_3 \right\}
$$

Comment: Okay, that is what I thought as well. If this is the case, then does that mean my book may not be defining sets to have unique elements only? Because $e_{2}$ would appear twice in $\left\{e_{1},e_{2},e_{2},e_{3}\right\}$, unless this is not considered a set. Also, the book proves the "if" direction of question using $\mathcal{B}_{\mathcal{X}}\cup\mathcal{B}_{\mathcal{Y}}$, so if the elements in this are unique, then there proof would have that error?

Comment: then their proof would have that error, as contradicted by question two?*

Comment: I think what they mean is that in the notation $\{ x_1, \dots, x_n,y_1, \dots, y_m\}$ even if two vectors are equal they are made distinct in these way because they are labeled with different names ($x_i$ versus $y_j$ for some i,j). About the "if" direction, the point is that if $\{ x_1, \dots, x_n,y_1, \dots, y_m\}$ is an set of linearly independent vectors, then also the set theoretic union of the basis is a set of linearly independent vectors.